# Gtk skip_taskbar_hint (seen in Glade-ui-Designer) equivalent in Qt

Tags: gtk, window-manager, qt

With Glade Designer that lets you set up Gtk-Ui's you can check the option that windows are not shown in the launcher. If I take a look at the ui-file generated by Glade, it says `<property name="skip_taskbar_hint">True</property>`. In gtk code this hint is  `window.set_property('skip-taskbar-hint', True)`. However I believe that this option is not exclusively Gtk-specific, and want to apply this one on my PyQt4-app. The Ubuntu window manager must be able to receive that hint, otherwise I would see the window of a gtk-application i use (stickynotes-indicator). So there MUST be a way of doing this in Qt or any other language, right?

Does anybody know such an option? Python or Qt syntax, doesn't matter!

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick:

```
object.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.SplashScreen)
```